# Accommodation at relative's during standard visit visa in UK

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am planning with my wife and 2 toddlers for UK standard visit visa from Saudi Arabia, although I'm from Pakistan. I have two sisters living in the UK. Both of their husbands are UK nationals.

1. Is it possible to show accommodation at my sister's place but that I'll bear all expenses bymyself and only accommodation is provided by them?
2. Is it necessary to submit their husband's bank statements or pay slip as I'm a bit reluctant to ask?

Answer (score 3):

1. **Yes**. Paragraph V4.3 of the [Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules) states that:

> A visitor’s travel, maintenance and accommodation may be provided by a third party where the decision maker is satisfied that they:
>
> (a) have a genuine professional or personal relationship with the visitor; and
>
> (b) are not, or will not be, in breach of UK immigration laws at the time of decision or the visitor’s entry to the UK; and
>
> (c) can and will provide support to the visitor for the intended duration of their stay.

You should provide a letter from your hosts in the U.K. confirming that you’ll be staying with them, and that they are legally allowed to offer the accommodation (eg no tenancy restrictions). Although not a requirement for a Visit visa, as you will be travelling with 2 small children your hosts should also explain the adequacy of their home to accommodate both your family and the existing occupiers.

2. **No**, bank statements are not necessary if hosts are not providing financial assistance. [Source](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673351/Visit-guidance-v7.0EXT.PDF)